# Using code to set MaxLength of textbox controls based on database or dataset column lengths

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, sql-server-2012

We have a form with many `TextBox` controls on it and would like to change the `MaxLength` of each one without manually doing it.

We would like to match the length of each to the same length as the database table or dataset column lengths.

Each `TextBox` is bound to the database using the `DataBindings` Text property of the datasource.

I was thinking maybe if this is possible, to loop through a controls collection and doing the same somehow through the columns of the dataset and checking if the control is a textbox and finding the length of each from the dataset and using that to set the `MaxLength` property but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: ASP.NET,Winforms,WPF,...? How are the TextBoxes connected to the database fields? Do you use some kind of databinding mechanism? How are you loading the data, ADO.NET(DataTable,DataReader,...), Entity Framework, LINQ-To-SQL, .... ? What DBMS are you using, SQL-Server, MySQL,Oracle, ....?

Comment: Yes, they are bound to the datasource in the DataBindings Text property of each textbox. The database is SQL Server 2012. I will add this information to the post to make it more clear.